# Implement search operation in multi user Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, search

Can anybody give me an efficient way to implement search operations in a multi-user windows application? The search form should have a `DataGridView` Control to display some related records to the searching user. Previously I did in one way in single user application:

I have created a static property:

```
static int _SrchRslt;
public static int SrchRslt
{
    get { return _SrchRslt; }
    set { _SrchRslt = value; }
}
```

and I have create the instance of search form as bello

```
SrchFrm srFm = new SrchFrm(this);
srFm.ShowDialog();

if (_SrchRslt > 0)                               
{
    //Retriving the data from database with _SrchRslt value which is comming from srchFrm.ShowDialog() form.
}
```

The `_SrchRslt` value is sending from the `SrchFrm.ShowDialog();` closed. This is not such a good idea for implementing a big multiuser application. My application has 25 forms.

Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this?

Comment: The cde's hrd t rd wtht vwls.

Comment: Can you describe what does "big multiuser application" mean, for a  WinForms app? What is the problem with showing a search dialog? Are all these users using the same PC simultaneously?

Comment: No All the users will use different Pcs with Onde database which will maintain server. and working with static property will take one's requested data to another user. thats it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whats in your `SrchFrm` but you could create a `UserControl` if you are using the same searching fields for multiple forms.

check this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557628/how-to-make-a-search-usercontrol-generic-in-net2-0-winforms)